# Can I stipulate template class members to be only of primitive type for C++03?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2008, c++03, primitive-types

I'm writing a template class for an older project that will be compiled with Visual Studio 2008, SP1. The template class uses a data `struct` that will be shared in a [named file-mapping object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) among several running processes. So the condition for my `IPC_SHARED_DATA` members is to contain only primitive data types that do not have constructors.

```
struct IPC_SHARED_DATA{
    //IMPORTANT: All members should not have constructors!

    int nVal;
    DWORD dwVal;
    BYTE bytes[16];
};
```

The questions is, can I set it as a condition in my `IPC_SHARED_MEM` template class?

```
template <class DATA_T>
class IPC_SHARED_MEM
{
public:
IPC_SHARED_MEM()
: hMutexIpc(NULL)
, hSharedMemIpc(NULL)
{
    //Initialization
    //...
}
~IPC_SHARED_MEM()
{
}

// ... other functions

private:
    DATA_T data;                //Data being passed in shared memory
    HANDLE hMutexIpc;           //IPC named mutex for synchronized access to 'data'
    HANDLE hSharedMemIpc;       //IPC named file mapping object handle
};
```

And it will be used as such:

```
IPC_SHARED_MEM<IPC_SHARED_DATA> globalSharedMem;
```

Comment: Obviously `std::is_pod` is out of the question, but what about [`boost::is_pod`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_pod.html)

Comment: @Tas: I don't use Boost. How is that method implemented?

Comment: Why not making template specialization for primitive types? Why types with no ctor, your `IPC_SHARED_MEM` may just use pointer to `IPC_SHARED_DATA`? Requiring a type with no ctor/initializer is just weird...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: It has to be only primitives that I can `memcpy` due to the IPC shared memory restriction.

Comment: Then define your own traits.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define truly generic `is_pod` trait in C++03. What you can do is to to "whitelist" primitive types and to allow whitelisting user classes. For example:

```
template<typename T> struct is_pod : public false_type {};

#define DEFINE_POD(type) template<> struct is_pod<type> : public true_type {}
DEFINE_POD(char); // continue with all predefined pod types

// Somewhere in user code:
class MyClass { int foo; };
DEFINE_POD(MyClass);
```

If `true_type` and `false_type` are not present in your library you can define them easily with whatever SFINAE switches you need:

```
struct true_type { 
  static const bool value = true;
  typedef bool type;
};
```

For example.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that *MS VS 2008 **SP1** does, specifically, [come with](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982918(v=vs.90).aspx) a partial TR1 implementation that includes `is_pod`. It is available as `std::tr1::is_pod`. Were that wrong and it isn't available, MSVC does provide a `__is_pod` intrinsic that can be converted into a template easily:

```
// is_pod
template <typename T> struct my_is_pod {
    enum { value = __is_pod(T) };
};
```

That said, I recall from experience that in VC 2008 those intrinsics can produce false positives, and the [documentation re intrinsics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177194(v=vs.90).aspx) does support that notion. You'll have to specialize accordingly. Caveat emptor.

Now, even though MSVC was quite behind as a compiler back then, it is still possible to backport or implement all the basic TR1 type traits by hand with either the definitions provided in TR1 documents or simply working out the cases from experience. I've chosen to [implement them on my own following the definitions](http://ryan.gulix.cl/fossil.cgi/cxxomfort/wiki?name=Features/IntegratedTypeTraits) for my cxxomfort library, for example; Boost has basically done something similar except *much* more precise. Once you have the basics such as `is_fundamental` defined, you can at least produce a version of `is_pod`, or a custom sidekick trait, that you can specialize further to your own purposes and shouldn't produce false positives, at least.

So, if you eg.: can't use Boost, you can still pick up the code from any of those libraries to peck at.

**EDIT** for completeness:

What you will be looking at, once you have a working version of `is_pod`, is code that will look like this:

```
template <class DATA_T>
class IPC_SHARED_MEM
{
static_assert (is_pod<DATA_T>::value, "DATA_T must be a pod type");

public:
IPC_SHARED_MEM()
: hMutexIpc(NULL)
, hSharedMemIpc(NULL)
{
    //Initialization
    //...
}
~IPC_SHARED_MEM()
{
}

// ... other functions

private:
    DATA_T data;                //Data being passed in shared memory
    HANDLE hMutexIpc;           //IPC named mutex for synchronized access to 'data'
    HANDLE hSharedMemIpc;       //IPC named file mapping object handle
};
```

That way, your class template will only compile into instantiations where `DATA_T` types that are provided fulfill the `is_pod` trait, and will otherwise fail to compile with an error message.

(Here I assume a backport of C++11's `static_assert`. Yes, I do that as well)

(Caveat emptor: I am the developer of `cxxomfort`, and MSVC 2008 *without* SP1 is one of my testbed environments)